# Do I add calcite or magnesium first to my new acid neutralizer?

Tags: plumbing

So I am replacing a smaller acid neutralizer with a larger one.  Bought it at the local water store, had a nice chat with Wolfgang.  He loaded 3 bags of calcite and one box of Magnesium mix.  He told me which goes in first but by the time I got around to installing it I forgot.  I think he said, "gravel -> 3 bags of calcite -> box of mag mix.  Is this right?

Comment: Why not simply make a telephone call back to the water store. Seems as you already know the name of the guy to talk to!!

Comment: Yeah I would but they close at noon on Saturday and are closed on Sunday.  I was just trying to get it done before Monday.

Answer (score 1):

So I called them today and the order is:

gravel -> box of mag mix -> bags of calcite.

Comment: You might want to draw a picture and tape it to the device.

Comment: Great Idea!!!!!